# Discrete Math: For this statement, are both of these answers equivalent?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Suppose the variable x represents students and the variable y represents courses, and

A(y): y is an advanced course F(x): x is a freshman T(x,y): x is taking y

Write the statement using these predicates and any needed quantifiers:
Some freshman is taking an advanced course.

I know that this first answer would be correct:
∃x∃y(F(x)∧A(y)∧T(x,y))

Would this also be an acceptable answer:
∃x∃y(T(F(x),A(y)))

Answer (score 1):

No, because $T$ expects a student as its first argument, and a course as its second argument, but you give it a Boolean. To make this less formal: $T$ expects

$$T(``user2012813", ``discrete\ math") = true $$

But the function $F(x)$ returns either true or false, and so does $A(y)$. So you are trying to evaluate

$$T(F(``user2012813"), A(``discrete\ math")) = T(true, false) = ?? $$

Only the first formulation makes sense, but you will get relations later on, and then you can use these sorts of constructs. Good luck!